# postman is getting 500 error while posting data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I am have been working with backend server. Here when i am trying to post data its giving me this error,

```
{
    "ok": 0,
    "code": 8000,
    "codeName": "AtlasError",
    "name": "MongoError"
}
```

Here this is my json raw format :

```
[
    {
        "username": "Sheba 2",
        "message": "Hey there Sheba3",
        "timestamp": "1601164075833"
    }
]
```

But in my terminal I am getting the post data when i run **npm start** command.

```
> node server.js

Listening on localhost: 9000
DB Connected
[
  {
    username: 'Sheba 1',
    message: 'Hey there Sheba3',
    timestamp: '1601164075833'
  }
]
```

Here this is my code sample, **server.js** file,

```
import Messages from './chatModel.js';
import Pusher from 'pusher';
import cors from 'cors';
//  Import Dependencies
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
// App Configuration
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;


// Create Middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

// Database Configuration
const mongoURI = 'mongodb+srv://chatappadmin:101010@cluster0.fw1gdf8.mongodb.net/ichatDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
mongoose.connect(mongoURI, {
  useNewurlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
  // useFindAndModify: true
    // serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1,
});
mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log('DB Connected');
});

// Add API Routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.status(200).send('Hello ChatApp Backend World'));

// app.post('/save/message', (req, res) => {
//   const dbMessage = req.body
//   console.log(dbMessage);
//   Messages.create(dbMessage, (err, data) => {
//     if (err) {
//       res.status(500).send(err)
//     } else {
//       res.status(201).send(data)
//     }
//   })
// });

app.post("/messages/new", (req, res) => {
  const dbMessage = req.body
  console.log(dbMessage);
  Messages.create(dbMessage, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
          res.status(500).send(err);
      } else {
          // res.status(201).send(`new messages created: \n ${data}`)
          res.status(201).send(data);
      }
  });
});

// Create listening ports
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on localhost: ${port}`));
```

Another file which i create my database models, **chatModel.js**:

```
// Creating the database models
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const chatSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  message: String, 
  timestamp: String, 
});

export default mongoose.model('messagecontents', chatSchema);
```

This is my **package.json** file setup which I am using,

```
{
  "name": "chat-app-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is our chat app backend server",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "codershona",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.11",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "pusher": "^5.1.1-beta"
  }
}
```

Here I am expecting when I do send request to post the data it should create the data, and i will receive **201 code created** in the postman.[image]

Comment: `console.log(err)`

Comment: Hello @Konrad after putting console.log(err) command i am getting this error in the terminal : > node server.js MongoError: user is not allowed to do action [insert] on [ichatDB.messagecontents]

Comment: (node:42202) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: the options [useNewurlParser] is not supported
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:42202) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
Listening on localhost: 9000
(node:42202) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Top-level use of w, wtimeout, j, and fsync is deprecated. Use writeConcern instead.

Comment: The mongo user that you created is not allowed to insert data into the database

Comment: @Konrad in that case what i gonna do?

Comment: @Konrad i have found this help me: In the Atlas cluster, select Security tab, press on button Edit then add a role readWriteAnyDatabase to the user. Try again or refresh your connection to see the result. in the mongodb